# If a var calls a function, does it execute each time the var is echoed?

Tags: php

Lets say I have a function that returns 1 and a var that is equal to the function so I can call it later.

```
function number() {
    return 1;
}

$var = number();
echo $var;
```

Will echoing the `$var` 10 times call `number()` 10 times? I only want the return value to be set as the variable. The actual function is quite heavy and can take a few seconds to execute so it's beneficial to only execute once. I don't want it to execute all 10 times that I echo. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The variable doesn't "call the function". You are calling the function and are assigning its result to the variable. This happens only once. The function returns a *value* which is assigned; you're not assigning the function.

Easy to proof:

```
function number() {
    echo 'function!';
    return 1;
}

echo 'assigning!';

$var = number();
echo $var;
echo $var;
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are storing the return value of the function in the variable. **The function will be called only once** and the variable will hold the value until the end of the script execution (unless you manually unset it). You can re-use it as many times as you want to.

Proof:

```
$count = 0;
function number() {
    global $count;
    $count++;
    return 1;
}

$initial = $count;
$var = number();
$final = $count;
printf('Function was executed %d time(s)', $final-$initial);

$initial = $count;
echo $var;
echo $var;
echo $var;
echo $var;
$final = $count;
printf('Function was executed %d time(s)', $final-$initial);
```

Output (excluding the `echo` outputs):

```
Function was executed 1 time(s)
Function was executed 0 time(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

a) Just try it. It's more quick than ask.

b) $var will have the first result returned by number

c) You may wrong with lambda functions like this each call is a new method call

```
$var = function () { return 1};
echo $var();
```